# An SQL view to show multiple addresses from one table from a table containing multiple address IDs

Tags: sql, join

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, but I cannot find it if it has. 
I have a table for a change of address form that has ID's for numerous addresses in it, CurrentAddressID and OldAddressID (which are mandatory) and LandlordAddressID (which is optional).

```
TableFormSubmissions
[Forename], 
[Surname], 
[Telephone], 
[CurrentAddressID], 
[OldAddressID], 
[LandlordAddressID]

TableAddresses
[HouseNumber], 
[Street], 
[District], 
[County], 
[Postcode]
```

I would like to make a view that would list:

```
Forename, 
Surname, 
Telephone,
HouseNumber (Current),
Street (Current),
District (Current),
County (Current),
Postcode (Current),
HouseNumber (Old),
Street (Old),
District (Old),
County (Old),
Postcode (Old),
HouseNumber (Landlord if provided),
Street (Landlord if provided),
District (Landlord if provided),
County (Landlord if provided),
Postcode (Landlord if provided)
```

My current SQL is a mess, doesn't work and has been omitted to save my embarrassment.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Post some example data for both tables and what you wish to get in your view. By the way, although stackoverflow.com has a flaming tradition, that should not prevent you from posting your best attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly

```
SELECT 
Forename, 
Surname, 
Telephone,
tsCurrent.HouseNumber [CurrentHouseNumber ],
tsCurrent.Street [CurrentStreet ],
tsCurrent.District [CurrentDistrict ],
tsCurrent.County [CurrentCounty ],
tsCurrent.Postcode [CurrentPostcode ],
tsOld.HouseNumber [OldHouseNumber ],
tsOld.Street [OldStreet ],
tsOld.District [OldDistrict ],
tsOld.County [OldCounty ],
tsOld.Postcode [OldPostcode ],
tsLandLord.HouseNumber [LandlordHouseNumber ],
tsLandLord.Street [LandlordStreet ],
tsLandLord.District [LandlordDistrict ],
tsLandLord.County [LandlordCounty ],
tsLandLord.Postcode [LandlordPostcode ] 
FROM TableFormSubmissions AS tfs
left JOIN TableAddresses AS tsCurrent ON tfs.CurrentAddressID = tsCurrent.AddressID
left JOIN TableAddresses AS tsOld ON tfs.CurrentAddressID = tsOld.AddressID
left JOIN TableAddresses AS tsLandLord ON tfs.CurrentAddressID = tsLandLord.AddressID
```

Comment: Thanks for this, my actual data structures are a bit more involved but with a few tweaks to the above I got it to work. My SQL was overly complex.